# What is the best way to compare treated/control samples?

Tags: differential-expression, p-values

I have two populations of mice, say RED and GREEN; there are 5 pairs treatment/control in each.

The table is the following:

```
gene_name  p-value(treatVSctrl) RED1_ctrl RED1_treat RED2_ctrl RED2_treat ... GRN1_ctrl GRN1_treat etc... 
gene1      1.3                  4         10         5         10             6.2       9.75
gene2      2.8                  3         6          6         12             3         6  
gene3      4.4                  5         12         4         8              7         10
```

I need to compare two groups to have an idea of the expression of different genes after treatment.
I also need to find a difference between RED and GREEN group in terms of genes expression

The thing is I cannot compare mice one by one just measuring the fold change, I need to consider p-value. What is the most correct way to perform this analysis?

Comment: Its an easy comparison but I was confused by the header p-values. I can't help there needs to be raw quantification. I am not aware of a stat that can take an unknown 'p-value' and compare to other p-values at a given level of significance

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean there must be a p-value for each pair?

Comment: No the header in the first column says " p-value(treatVSctrl..." . I don't understand the quantification, but the column header is stating this is a p-value.

Comment: Agree the "consider the p-value" instruction is confusing. The first column clearly doesn't represent p-values, as p-value are probabilities and must be in the range [0, 1].

Comment: Is this RNA-seq? How many genes are there in total and how many samples per group? The suggested Wilcox is not very powerful so it would only work if your group size is sufficient, and if this is RNA-seq then you sould use established software such as DESeq2 or edgeR which takes care of the stats and all the necessary internals. Are these data normalized already, what is the experiment?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie it could represent a percentage, i.e. (0 to 1.0) * 100 , e.g. this could be a pairwise T-test. Alot of values are hovering around the 5% mark. Where there are mixed results it would be a reason for the OP to ask how to move forward.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand the table, particularly the 'p-value' in the header. More generally I don't really understand the experiment nor the data.

As a general rule the Wilcoxon would be a reasonable guess of the test using raw data. This is non-parametric version of the T-test without the rigid assumptions of parametrics. Control mice go in one column and subjects in the other. Scipy.stats has the test, its certainly in R (which I don't really use).

```
print (scipy.stats.wilcoxon(x = [1,2,3,4,5], y=[1,3,5,6,7], zero_method='wilcox', correction=False, alternative='two-sided', mode='auto', *, axis=0, nan_policy='propagate'))
```

There you go, filled out with some example data.